# Unix group becomes everyone when assigned to a group ID that does not exist

Tags: group

Can you please assist why the ID is assigned to a group named everyone?

```
# id entitlement
uid=315(entitlement) gid=200(everyone) groups=200(everyone)
```

Below commands do not return anything:

```
# cat /etc/group | grep everyone
# cat /etc/group | grep 200
```

No NIS is configured, so `ypcat` is not available.
I tried doing it to another group but this time it is failing.

```
# usermod -g 201 entitlement
usermod: group '201' does not exist
```

I am trying to search but can't find any feature of Linux that does this.

Here is the content of my `nsswitch.conf`

```
passwd:     files sss

shadow:     files sss

group:      files sss
```

getent found the everyone group, not sure where I am able to get this from sss. is there a command I can confirm where from sss this group is?

Comment: Since GID #200 is successfully mapped to group name `everyone` without it existing in `/etc/group`, the system *must* have some additional group name resolution method configured. What is the output of `grep group: /etc/nsswitch.conf`?

Comment: Running `strace -f id entitlement` may give you a clue as to where it is picking this group up from. A group number of 200 is rather suspicious and suggests it may have something to do with installed software. As `usermod -g 200 ...` failed, try running it against a different user and see if you can set its gid to 200.

Comment: it's probably the primary group for that user in `/etc/passwd` (and/or whatever else your nsswitch.conf is configured to use for passwd entries).  Check with `getent passwd entitlement`.    The group can be listed with `getent group 200`.  BTW, don't examine `/etc/passwd` or `/etc/group` directly, especially if you're going to use other services like NIS.  Use `getent` instead.

Comment: I'm sure I read somewhere that a common PAM module read not only `/etc/group` but some other file too. But I can't find a reference except for the `extrausers`option in `nsswitch.conf` so I could be mistaken

Comment: telcoM roaima  This is the content of my nsswitch.conf

passwd:     files sss

shadow:     files sss

group:      files sss

Comment: So you are using System Security Services Daemon (SSSD). https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system-level_authentication_guide/sssd

Answer (score 1):

You're using SSS, typically (but not exclusively) used to get organisation-wide information from Active Directory or LDAP.

You will need to talk with your machine's System Administrator to find out more about the `everyone` group. You may also want to take a look at the file `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf` to see the configuration for the connection.

You may be able to find out some summary information about the join to the network authentication/authorisation service with `realm list`.

Finally, to list information about a group or user that is not in `/etc/group` you can use the `getent` command:

```
getent passwd entitlement
getent group everyone
```